# SAS: Date intervals including 15th of several months

Tags: sas

I have difficulties coming up with a nice code for counting the number of times date intervals includes the 15th of the month between 01.01.2019-31.12.2020. As a simple example we can consider the two intervals:

```
Obs | DateStart | DateEnd
 
 1    14Oct2019  20Mar2020
 2    13Nov2018  29Jan2020
```

I want to determine how many overlaps these have with the 15th of the months between 01Jan2019-31Dec2020. In the end I would like to produce a crosstable showing year in rows and months in columns with a count for each time the above intervals included the 15th of the month. From the above two date intervals, I would like an output like the following:

```
Months: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12
2019    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    2    2    2 
2020    2   1   1   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .
```

I am currently trying to set up a dataset with columns 1 through 24, which I will then reformat and later cross in a proc freq. This seems like the long way around, and I am having trouble identifying when the date intervals include the 15th of any month.

I have ~100 observations to do this for. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the date range and output to a second data set (or view) when the date is a 15th.  The second data set can be tabulated for frequency counts.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(2021);

  do _n_ = 1 to 1000;
    date1 = today() - rand('integer', 2500);
    date2 = date1 + rand('integer', 720);
    output;
  end;
run;

data _15ths(keep=year month);
  set have;
  do date = date1 to date2;
    if day(date) ne 15 then continue;
    year = year(date);
    month = month(date);
    output;
  end;
run;

proc tabulate data=_15ths;
  title 'Number of date ranges with a 15th';

  class year month;
  table year='',month*n=''/nocellmerge box='year';
run;
```

Will produce the following output

[image]

Comment: This worked brilliantly! Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Took me ages to figure out why the code was not immediately applicable to my dataset. I had empty date2s (indicating no end date as of yet) which messed it up. Closing those using today() worked.